# Form is posting back multiple times if there are multiple grids in a view (Kendo Grid MVC)

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have 3 Kendo grids and a Save button in a view. When I click on Save button, I get the updated ViewModel in my controller’s action method which in turns add/update records in database. But the save action method is called 3 times because there are 3 kendo grids on the view. I removed 2 grids from the view and it post backs only time since the view has only one grid (weird).

How to stop multiple postbacks when the Save button is clicked?

Index.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "UDFController", FormMethod.Post))
{

<input class="button" type="submit" name="save" value="Save"/>


@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.List1)
                     .Name("List1")
                     .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:auto;height:100%" })
                     .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Add New Record"))
                     .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).CreateAt(GridInsertRowPosition.Top))
                     .Columns(columns =>
                         {
                             columns.Bound(p => p.Title)
                                     .ClientTemplate("#= Title #" +
                                        "<input type='hidden' name='DateFields[#= index(data)#].Title' value='#= Title #' />")
                                     .Title("Title").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:30%" });
                             columns.Bound(p => p.MaxPrecision).Title("Decimal Places")
                                     .ClientTemplate("#= MaxPrecision #" +
                                            "<input type='hidden' name='DateFields[#= index(data)#].MaxPrecision' value='#= MaxPrecision #' />");                                 
                             columns.Bound(p => p.IsObsolete).Title("Obsolete")
                                 .ClientTemplate("#= IsObsolete #" +
                                            "<input type='hidden' name='DateFields[#= index(data)#].IsObsolete' value='#= IsObsolete #' />");
                         })
                    .DataSource(datasource => datasource
                        .Ajax()
                        .Model(model =>
                                {
                                    {
                                        model.Id(p => p.Title);
                                        model.Field(p => p.Title).Editable(true);
                                        model.Field(p => p.MaxPrecision).Editable(true);
                                        model.Field(p => p.IsObsolete).Editable(true);                                    
                                    }
                                }
                            )

                        )

                    )



@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.List2)
                     .Name("List2")
                     .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:auto;height:100%" })
                     .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Add New Record"))
                     .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).CreateAt(GridInsertRowPosition.Top))
                     .Columns(columns =>
                         {
                             columns.Bound(p => p.Title)
                                     .ClientTemplate("#= Title #" +
                                        "<input type='hidden' name='DateFields[#= index(data)#].Title' value='#= Title #' />")
                                     .Title("Title").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:30%" });
                             columns.Bound(p => p.MaxPrecision).Title("Decimal Places")
                                     .ClientTemplate("#= MaxPrecision #" +
                                            "<input type='hidden' name='DateFields[#= index(data)#].MaxPrecision' value='#= MaxPrecision #' />");                                 
                             columns.Bound(p => p.IsObsolete).Title("Obsolete")
                                 .ClientTemplate("#= IsObsolete #" +
                                            "<input type='hidden' name='DateFields[#= index(data)#].IsObsolete' value='#= IsObsolete #' />");
                         })
                    .DataSource(datasource => datasource
                        .Ajax()
                        .Model(model =>
                                {
                                    {
                                        model.Id(p => p.Title);
                                        model.Field(p => p.Title).Editable(true);
                                        model.Field(p => p.MaxPrecision).Editable(true);
                                        model.Field(p => p.IsObsolete).Editable(true);                                    
                                    }
                                }
                            )

                        )

                    )

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.List3)
                     .Name("List3")
                     .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:auto;height:100%" })
                     .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Add New Record"))
                     .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).CreateAt(GridInsertRowPosition.Top))
                     .Columns(columns =>
                         {
                             columns.Bound(p => p.Title)
                                     .ClientTemplate("#= Title #" +
                                        "<input type='hidden' name='DateFields[#= index(data)#].Title' value='#= Title #' />")
                                     .Title("Title").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:30%" });
                             columns.Bound(p => p.MaxPrecision).Title("Decimal Places")
                                     .ClientTemplate("#= MaxPrecision #" +
                                            "<input type='hidden' name='DateFields[#= index(data)#].MaxPrecision' value='#= MaxPrecision #' />");                                 
                             columns.Bound(p => p.IsObsolete).Title("Obsolete")
                                 .ClientTemplate("#= IsObsolete #" +
                                            "<input type='hidden' name='DateFields[#= index(data)#].IsObsolete' value='#= IsObsolete #' />");
                         })
                    .DataSource(datasource => datasource
                        .Ajax()
                        .Model(model =>
                                {
                                    {
                                        model.Id(p => p.Title);
                                        model.Field(p => p.Title).Editable(true);
                                        model.Field(p => p.MaxPrecision).Editable(true);
                                        model.Field(p => p.IsObsolete).Editable(true);                                    
                                    }
                                }
                            )

                        )

                    )

}
```

Controller Code

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(ListViewModel viewModel)
    {
        //This is getting called 3 times. But this is supposed to be called 1 time
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (viewModel != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    viewModel.Save(viewModel);
                    return View("Index", viewModel); 
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return View("Index", viewModel);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is to be expected since you have 3 ajax enabled grids.  Since they are setup as ajax grids they should operate independent of one another.

Comment: thank you for replying but I am not sure if I understood your answer correctly. whats your suggestion? if I remove .Ajax() will it not be posing back 3 times?

Comment: I don't think it's going to work how you're wanting it to.  What problem are you having with separate requests?  Are your grids all showing the same data?

Comment: if you see Save() action, you will notice that there is a database save call (viewModel.Save(viewModel);). If there are seperate requests then everytime database call will get executed which I don't want.

Comment: if you see Save() action, you will notice that there is a database save call (viewModel.Save(viewModel);). If there are seperate requests then everytime database call will get executed which I don't want. All grids are not showing same data. Each grid is bound to different property of the model which is IenumerableList.

Comment: You could save to the Session in your grid ajax calls, then save all the edits to the database in one unit of work if you'd like.  Are you sure the separate database calls are that much concern?  It might be a big hassle.  Since your grids have similar data, could you maybe combine them and filter on a new column to differentiate on?  You could possibly have a hidden column that stores which list it's a part of and filter your editable grid by that value whenever the user clicks between links or tabs or something.

Answer (score 0):

I think if null is passed to the  Datasource of the kendo Grid in the html helper, the Grid will be built in `remote  data mode` rather than `local data mode` and since the read Url is not set the current browser Url will be used for the read operation.

The fix is very easy just make sure to initialize the list in the Model before using it as a Datasource.

Like this:

```
Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.List1) 
Model.List1 needs to be initialized.
```